# php: string compare

Tags: php

The simple code is written below i m not getting 0 when i m running this code

```
<?php
 echo "<script>
     name=prompt('a code is sent to u','vivek')
      </script>";
 $code="<script>document.write(name);</script>";
 echo $code;
 $v='vivek';
 $n=strcmp($v,$code);
 echo $n;
 ?>
```

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong heading previously

Answer (score 1):

**Seriously?!** `JS` is client side, `PHP` is server side. When `JS` runs, `PHP` has long before closed. Only `AJAX` allows communication between them.

`PHP` is a printer, it generates `HTML` for a page. Then ships it to the browser. Only then `JS` kicks in. No communication back and forth unless you specifically devise a method.